# Experiencing random freezes on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, mouse, freeze

I get like a random freeze once every hour, making it very tedious to do any sort of work. When the freeze happens I can still move my mouse. I have tried a number of different key combinations to make the system respond (including CTRL+ALT+F1 to switch to terminal view) but none of them seem to work. Some of them even make the mouse no longer work. I'm using a NVIDIA GTX 670 with the standard Nouveau driver and dual monitors (if that matters).

Comment: Does it freeze with the Nvidia driver?

Comment: I tried Nvidia before, it didn't freeze but I suspect those drivers caused another bug, which basically forced me to reinstall the entire OS. That's why I have now switched to Nouveau.

Comment: Is it every hour at a specific time, or about every hour or so?  Can you check the state of your memory with `free -h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the latest stable NVIDIA drivers supporting GTX670 from the Proprietary GPU drivers PPA.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Note 1 : If you ever had NVIDIA drivers installed - uninstall every NVIDIA related software before.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Note 2 : In case you have a **notebook** with **switchable graphics** install **Optimus support** as well.

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-prime
```

Comment: But those drivers don't get updated automatically when the kernel does, right? So I would run into trouble once that happens? The reason I'm asking is that I had those installed before and I ran into a bug when trying to log in, forcing me to reinstall the entire OS, which made me switch to Nouveau.

Comment: @Soggiorno : A kernel update normally does not generate issues regarding the NVIDIA drivers - so when the drivers worked before a kernel update ... they will work after a kernel update as well. :)

Comment: Alright, maybe the bug was something else then. I will try Nvidia again and  see how it goes.  Thanks.